# How can I show the value of a hidden input field if the value is defined?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".city_name").click(function() {
    city = this.id;
    course = $("#courses").val();
    course_type = $("#courses_type").val();
    course_type2 = $("#courses_type2").val();
    course_type3 = $("#courses_type3").val();
    alert(course);
    alert(courses_type);
    alert(courses_type2);
    alert(courses_type3);
    alert(city);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "id": city,
        "courses": course,
        "courses_type": course_type,
        "courses_type2": course_type2,
        "courses_type3": course_type3
      },
      url: "filter-city-colleges.php",
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="city_name"> Click me
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" id="courses_type" value="field">
    <input type="hidden" id="courses_type2" value="univer">
    <input type="hidden" id="courses_type3" value="course">
```

In this code when I am alert courses_type, courses_type2, courses_type3 in jquery, It show [objectHTMLcollection]. How to retrieve the value of hidden input box.

Comment: Why are you alerting at wrong location ?

Comment: share `filter-city-colleges.php`  code also ?

Comment: There is no problem. alert the required things after retrieving it

Comment: You have to do small change , try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478527/how-can-i-show-value-of-hidden-input-filed-if-the-value-is-define/42480190#42480190

Comment: Fixed typo and added clarity to title

Answer (score 0):

When `var` keyword is not used before a variable , it will be defined in global space

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".city_name").click(function(){
    var city=this.id;
    course = $("#courses").val(); // cannot find any DOM with id courses
    var course_type = $("#courses_type").val();
    alert(course);    // It will alert undefined since there is no DOM with id course

    alert(courses_type); // will alert field
    var course_type2 = $("#courses_type2").val();
    var course_type3 = $("#courses_type3").val();
    // put the alert here after retriving the value from DOM, before retrieving it will be undefined
    alert(courses_type2);
    alert(courses_type3);
    alert(city);
    $.ajax({
        // rest of the ajax
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to pass all hiddedn fields with values to ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".city_name").click(function(){
            city=this.id;
            course = $("#courses").val();

            var data = {};
            $('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).val()){
                    data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
                }
            });
            data['id'] = city;
            data['course'] = 'course';

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:data,
                url:"filter-city-colleges.php",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the correct variable name inside `alert()` function, for example you have a variable with name `course_type` but you mentioned `course**s**_type` inside the alert. just change it :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".city_name").click(function() {
    city = this.id;
    course = $("#courses").val();
    course_type = $("#courses_type").val();
    course_type2 = $("#courses_type2").val();
    course_type3 = $("#courses_type3").val();
    // alert(course);
    alert(course_type);
    alert(course_type2);
    alert(course_type3);
    alert(city);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "id": city,
        "courses": course,
        "courses_type": course_type,
        "courses_type2": course_type2,
        "courses_type3": course_type3
      },
      url: "filter-city-colleges.php",
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="city_name" id="cityId"> Click me
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" id="courses_type" value="field" />
    <input type="hidden" id="courses_type2" value="univer" />
    <input type="hidden" id="courses_type3" value="course" />
```